# Como hacer Responsive mi pagina

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('active', window.scrollY > 0)
})
```

```css
* {
  /* Para establecer estilos globales */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  /* Estilos del body */
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #f1f7f9;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}


/* Encabezado de página (Header) */


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


/* Agregar imagen de fondo al encabezado */

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  height: 10vh;
}

.nav {
  /* Controla el posicionamiento de los elementos dentro del nav */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.nav.active {
  /* Barra de navegación activa */
  background: #075270;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 100px;
}

.nav.active .logo,
.nav.active a {
  /* Cuando la barra de navegación está activa cambia el color de las clases logo y a */
  color: #fff;
}

.nav.active a:hover {
  /* Cambia el estilo cuando movemos el mouse encima del elemento */
  color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  transition: transform 0.7s ease;
}

.nav.active .menu {
  transform: translate(450px, -50px);
}

.menu {
  /* Estilos para la clase menu */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.menu li a.link-up::before {
  content: "";
  background: #000;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -6px;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

.menu li a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav.active .menu li a.link-down::before {
  background: #fff;
  /* Color del subrayado cuando la barra baja */
}

.scroll {
  height: 100px;
}

.imagen-barra {
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, filter 0.5 ease;
}

.nav.active .imagen-barra {
  filter: invert(100%);
  /* Invierte el color al activar la barra */
}

.nav.active .vertical-bar {
  filter: invert(100%);
  /* Invierte el color al activar la barra */
}

.imagen-barra:hover {
  /* Elevación de la imagen en el eje y */
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.vertical-bar {
  width: 2px;
  /* Ancho de la barra vertical */
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #000000;
  /* Color de la barra vertical */
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* Espacio entre la barra vertical y los elementos de la lista */
  transition: transform 0.7s ease;
}

.nav.active .vertical-bar {
  transform: translate(450px, -50px);
}

.elementos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}


/* imagenes-arriba */

.mi-imagen {
  width: 60px;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav.active .mi-imagen {
  transform: translate(-620px, 0px);
}

.odontoarte-img {
  width: 200px;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.nav.active .odontoarte-img {
  transform: translate(-620px, 0px);
}


/* Contenido (Main) */


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.container-quienes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section .article-quienessomos {
  background-color: #c6d4d9;
}

section article div .img-art1 {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  /* ARRIBA - DERECHA - ABAJO - IZQUIERDA */
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* derecha, abajo, difuminación, color */
}

section article div h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

section article div .quienessomos {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

section article div p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section article div nav .quienessomos {
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.container-importancia {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section article div .img-art2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
  /* ARRIBA - DERECHA - ABAJO - IZQUIERDA */
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* derecha, abajo, difuminación, color */
}


/* ANIMACIÓN SLIDER */

.slider-frame {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.slider-frame ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 500%;
  animation: slide 20s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

.slider-frame li {
  width: 20%;
  list-style: none;
}

.slider-frame img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}

.cont1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.cont1 .img-grande {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* derecha, abajo, difuminación, color */
}

.img-cont1 {
  width: 20px;
}

.nav3 ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: static;
}

.nav3 ul li img {
  position: static;
  padding-top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.nav3 h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
}

.nav3 .p2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
}

.content {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #c6d4d9;
}

.sau {
  padding: 40px;
  background: #c6d4d9;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.content h2 {
  background: #c6d4d9;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 40px 0 10px 0;
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-container .box {
  height: 11rem;
  width: 17rem;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin: 80px 40px 80px 40px;
}

.box-container .box h3 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #000;
}

.box-container .box p {
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.about {
  background-color: #171717;
}

.contact {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #171717;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .sau {
    height: 120vh;
  }
  .navbar {
    display: none;
  }
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  /* Cambiado a 100% para ocupar todo el ancho */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.info2 {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.imagedoc {
  width: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 90px;
  /* Añadido px a la propiedad de radio */
  margin-right: 80px;
  /* Corregido el error de sintaxis en la propiedad de margen */
  display: flex;
  /* Añadido para centrar la imagen */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Centrado horizontal de la imagen */
  align-items: center;
  /* Centrado vertical de la imagen */
}

.imagedoc img {
  width: 100%;
  /* Cambiado a 100% para que la imagen sea responsive */
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 20%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #007BFF;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.more-info {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}


/* Pie de página (Footer) */


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

footer {
  background-color: #04364A;
  /* Color al pie de página */
  color: #fff;
  /* Color de las letras */
  text-align: center;
  /* Centrado del texto */
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav2 {
  position: static;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Anchor del pie de página */
  display: block;
  /* se utiliza para controlar como se muestra un elemento */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 25px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.contacto {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
}

.contacto li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 7px;
  position: static;
}

.contacto li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* grosor de la negrita */
}

.contacto img {
  /* Alinea verticalmente las imágenes con el texto */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.imageny {
  /* tiempo de la transición */
  display: inline;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.imageny:hover {
  /* Elevación de la imagen en el eje y */
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

p {
  /* espaciado entre los párrafos */
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Agrega tus animaciones aquí */

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

body {
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html land="es">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200&family=Jost:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


  <title>OdontoArte</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div navbar>
      <nav class="nav">
        <nav class="img-grande">
          <img class="mi-imagen" id="miImagen" src="imagenes/logoo.png"><img class="odontoarte-img" src="imagenes/odontoarte-letra.png" alt="">
        </nav>
        <nav class="elementos">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="Inicio.html" class="link-up link-down">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="Tratamientos.html" class="link-up link-down">Tratamientos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-up link-down">Profesional</a></li>
            <li><a href="Agendamientos.html" class="link-up link-down">Agendamiento</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="vertical-bar"></div>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><img src="imagenes/instagram2.svg" alt="instagram/imagen" width="20" class="imagen-barra"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/ubicacion2.svg" alt="ubicacion/imagen" width="20" class="imagen-barra"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/bxl-whatsapp.svg" alt="facebook/imagen" width="20" class="imagen-barra"></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <!-- contenido -->
    <section>
      <article class="slider">
        <div class="slider-frame">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="Imagenes/Doctor.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="Imagenes/Doctor.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="Imagenes/Doctor.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="Imagenes/Doctor.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img src="Imagenes/Doctor.jpg" alt=""></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <article id="container1">
        <div class="cont1">
          <img class="img-grande" src="Imagenes/Doctor.jpg" alt="">
          <nav class="nav3">
            <h2>Contacto y Horarios</h2>
            <p>
              <ul>
                <li><img class="img-cont1" src="imagenes/whatsapp2.png" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;(+595)&nbsp;0971&nbsp;212184</li>
                <li><img class="img-cont1" src="imagenes/instagram2.png" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;odontoarte</li>
                <li><img class="img-cont1" src="imagenes/ubicación2.png" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;Gral. MAC Athur c/ Quesada N°232</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p class="p2">Lunes a viernes de 08:00Hs. a 20:00Hs.</p>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
      <h2 class="title">Los Tratamientos Que Ofrecemos</h2>
      <p>
        "Descubre una sonrisa perfecta con nuestros tratamientos de ortodoncia y cirugía oral. Enfocados en la estética dental, ofrecemos soluciones personalizadas para realzar tu belleza natural. ¡Cuida de tu sonrisa con nosotros!"
      </p>
      <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-tooth"></i>
          <h3>Ortodoncia</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-discourse"></i>
          <h3>Cirujía</h3>
          <p>illaaaapsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-square-font-awesome-stroke"></i>
          <h3>Estética</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="info2">
        <h1>Dr.Lorem</h1>
        <p>Especialista en Salud Bucal con mas de 20 años de experiencia.</p>
        <button id="more-info-button" class="button">Más información</button>
        <div id="more-info" class="more-info">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste temporibus non quis corporis, harum ducimus eveniet provident repellendus facilis aperiam perspiciatis numquam officiis ratione illum vero facere natus odit error.</p>
          <p>Residencia: Hospital Italiano de Asuncion, 2002-2005</p>
          <!-- Más información... -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="imagedoc">
        <img src="Imagenes/66392966_119118669368287_4546989300238498014_n.jpg" alt="Dr. Juan Pérez">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('more-info-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var moreInfo = document.getElementById('more-info');
        if (moreInfo.style.maxHeight) {
          moreInfo.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          moreInfo.style.maxHeight = moreInfo.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      });
    </script>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="divfooter">
      <nav class="nav2">
        <p align="center">© 2023 OdontoArte</p>
        <p align="center">
          <ul class="contacto">
            <li>Gral. MAC Athur c/ Quesada N°232&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/ubicación.png" alt="ubicación/imagen" width="23" height="21" class="imageny"></a>
            </li>
            <li>(+595) 0971212184&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/whatsapp.png" alt="facebook/imagen" width="25" class="imageny"></a>
            </li>
            <li>odontoarte&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/instagram.png" alt="instagram/imagen" width="25" class="imageny"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </p>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <div class="scroll"></div>
  <script src="menu.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Ya que me parece muy interesante todo lo relacionado a paginas web que he practicado en esto por cuenta propia, pero no puedo encontrar una solucion a mi problema con el responsive.
Soy algo nuevo en el tema de paginas web, y queria una ayuda para ver como hacer que mi pagina sea responsive, lo intente de todo y se ve peor con cada modificacion
Siguiendo un tutorial de como hacer responsive mi codigo, me quedo totalmente distinto a como la persona lo realizo
Si algun experto me sepa dar una respuesta lo agradeceria, muchisimas gracias :)

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, puedes buscar un poco en internet y te toparas con Grids, flex, medias querys y seguramente algunos frameworks. Solo es cuestión de investigar y aprender.

Answer (score 1):

Yo, a nivel personal, te recomendaría que aprendas responsividad con un Framework fácil como es Bootstrap (BS). Si comienzas con CSS puro, te vas a desanimar.

Con BS hacer responsiva una web es como el siguiente ejemplo:

Página Nada Responsiva. Ambos Divs inician con un margen y padding determinado y todo es obsoleto y aburrido. La tabla es HORRIBLE!!!

```css
.div1{
            background-color: #2A9AF9;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .div2{
            background-color: pink;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web Nada Responsiva</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1">
        Este div cubre todo mi espacio web y está sobre el Div2
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        Este div cubre todo mi espacio web y está bajo el Div1
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
            <td>Contenido</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Vinculando Bootstrap

Página algo mejor. Ambos Divs ocupan solo las columnas que yo quiero y tienen un estilo mas vistoso. La tabla, con una sola clase, ya se ve mejor. Pero aun no es Responsiva

```css
.div1{
            background-color: #2A9AF9;
      display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .div2{
            background-color: pink;
      display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="div1 col-lg-6">
                Este div cubre 6 de 12 columnas
            </div>
            <div class="div2 col-lg-6">
                Este div cubre 6 de 12 columnas
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
                <td>Contenido</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Pagina mucho mejor. La tabla, con unas cuantas clases la hice super bonita. Además, envolviéndola en un div con la clase `table-responsive` la tabla se vuelve responsiva.

```css
.div1{
            background-color: #2A9AF9;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .div2{
            background-color: pink;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="div1 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                Este div cubre 6 columnas en grande y 12 en pequeño
            </div>
            <div class="div2 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                Este div cubre 6 columnas en grande y 12 en pequeño
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                <tr class="table-dark">
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                    <td>Contenido</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que te he mostrado, es solo el 1% de todo lo que puedes hacer con Bootstrap. Mi consejo? Busca un tuto de BS en Youtube y no lo pienses más.

Comment: Gracias, esto me va a ayudar mucho. Como al principio me dijeron que aprenda html4 que es obsoleto y luego vaya al html5, y con el css ya me estoy estresando jajaja, mirare un tuto de BS y lo hare.

Comment: Siempre aprende lo ultimo, de que sirve algo obsoleto? Con Bootstrap vas  abrir los ojos y te darás cuenta como manejar tu CSS luego. Pero Usa BS en local, bájalo, porque por CDN no tendrás el código en local y adelante!!!