# Organización de imagnes y texto

Tags: html, css

gente, es primera vez que hago una consulta por aquí soy nuevo en la programación con HTML y CSS, estoy intentando colocar unos vectores y debajo de los vectores unos textos relacionados con el vector, hasta ahí todo bien, en dispositivos móviles se mira en el orden uno debajo del otro y en escritorio o sea en PC también aparece igual, no quiero que se vea así, quiero que en PC se vea uno al lado del otro, mientras que en móvil la organización está perfecta, ¿cómo puedo lograr que se vea uno del lado del otro en pc? Ahí va el código como lo llevo...
A demas que cuando lo logro ejecutar uno al lado del otro en PC sale desordenado todo.
Gracias

```css
<style>
       .imagenes {
    text-align: center; /* Centra las imágenes horizontalmente */
     color: #2E2A39
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .imagenes img {
      margin: 10px; /* Ajusta el espaciado entre las imágenes según tus necesidades */
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-right: 10;

    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .imagenes {
       margin: 10px; /* Ajusta el espaciado vertical entre las imágenes según tus necesidades */
    }
}
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="imagenes">
        &nbsp
         <div><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0627/3548/3086/files/truck.svg?v=1701537341" width="125" height="55"></div>
        
        <b><tittle>Envios a todo Colombia</tittle></b>
        <div>Regular o express</div>
        &nbsp
          <div><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0627/3548/3086/files/estrella.svg?v=1701538183" width="125" height="45"></div>
        <b><tittle>Productos con garantía</tittle></b>
        <div>Por defectos de fábrica</div>
        &nbsp
          <div><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0627/3548/3086/files/3.svg?v=1701538449" width="125" height="75"></div>
        <b><tittle>Pagos seguros</tittle></b>
        <div>PSE</div>
        &nbsp
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yo haría el código un poco más limpio y ordenado.

```css
/* movil */
        @media (max-width: 500px) {
            .container{
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
        }
        .container{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .box{
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="box" style="background-color: teal;">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0627/3548/3086/files/truck.svg?v=1701537341" width="125" height="55">
            <div>Envios a todo Colombia</div>
            <div>Regular o express</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: pink;">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0627/3548/3086/files/estrella.svg?v=1701538183" width="125" height="45">
            <div>Productos con garantía</div>
            <div>Por defectos de fábrica</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="background-color: orange;">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0627/3548/3086/files/3.svg?v=1701538449" width="125" height="45">
            <div>Pagos seguros</div>
            <div>PSE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

El resto del estilo lo dejo a tu gusto.

Pueda que [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/609029/como-hacer-responsive-mi-pagina/609034#609034) te ayude también.

Comment: Gracias mano, me funcinó!

Comment: Gracias. Acepta la respuesta entonces, para que no quede perdida por ahí.

Answer (score 1):

para lograr que las imágenes y los textos aparezcan uno al lado del otro en dispositivos de escritorio y uno debajo del otro en dispositivos móviles, puedes ajustar el código CSS y el HTML de la siguiente manera:

Primero, ajusta tu HTML para agrupar cada imagen con su respectivo título y texto en un contenedor. Esto ayudará a organizar mejor el contenido:

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .imagenes {
            text-align: center;
            color: #2E2A39;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: 0 auto; /* Centra el contenedor horizontalmente */
            max-width: 800px; /* Ajusta el ancho máximo según tus necesidades */
        }

        .item {
            flex: 1;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .item img {
            width: 100%;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            .item {
                flex: 100%;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="imagenes">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0627/3548/3086/files/truck.svg?v=1701537341" width="125" height="55">
    <b><title>Envíos a todo Colombia</title></b>
    <div>Regular o express</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0627/3548/3086/files/estrella.svg?v=1701538183" width="125" height="45">
    <b><title>Productos con garantía</title></b>
    <div>Por defectos de fábrica</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0627/3548/3086/files/3.svg?v=1701538449" width="125" height="75">
    <b><title>Pagos seguros</title></b>
    <div>PSE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que esto pueda ayudar.

Comment: Gracias funcionó!